# Set first row values as column names sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I have imported a CSV file into DB browser for SQLite and I don't know how to simply set the column names as the values in the first row.

There are 100+ columns so I would prefer not to do this manually.

[image]

Comment: How did you imported CSV file to sqlite? If there is any tool then there must be an option to set first row as a column names.

Comment: As above i'm using DB browser for SQLite .. If there is such an option, it isn't clear where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File/Import/Table as CSV when the pop is displayed select (tick) ***Column names in the first line*** :-

[image]

And your get :-

[image]